# How to Filter a Content in Spring integration /

Tags: spring, design-patterns, integration, spring-integration

we have the filter configuration which decides to drop and pass the message to the channels but I am trying to filter the message attributes based on the content filter pattern

Message{attr1; attr2} -> subscriber 1
Message{attr1} -> subscriber2

the requirement to drop and add a message attribute has to be dynamic.

One way of doing this is to set the null to the attributes which has to be filtered so that the channel drops it, but is there a better way to do it in spring.

[Content filter](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html/Implementing_Enterprise_Integration_Patterns/files/images/content_filter.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misread your question.

Here's a proper link to the [content filter](http://www.eaipatterns.com/ContentFilter.html).

You would use a transformer for that; for a complex solution (variable filtering), you could use a POJO or a groovy script to manipulate the payload.

BTW, channels don't "drop" anything, endpoints do.